How can I serve multiple websockets in a single python script?
I need to serve 6 different web sockets but the program doesnt move on to open the next one while its running the first.
I've been using Websockets and asyncio..
Is there a way to put them into the background or run them in different threads without running 6 different python scripts to serve the 6 sockets?
example:
import asyncio
from websockets.server import serve

async def echo (websocket,path):
  print("A client just connect to 20781 {path}")
  await websocket.send(json.dumps(json_data)

async def main():
  async with serve(echo, "localhost", 20781):
  print(f"starting 20781 socket")
  await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()

..Tried putting second socket here...
asyncio.run(main())


The example you shared has indentation errors - it won't run at all like this. Please share code that runs and that demonstrates the problem you have, and explain what happens and what you expected to happen instead.

You need to start each server in the background using asyncio tasks. You can do something like this:
import asyncio
from websockets.server import serve
import json

async def echo(websocket, path):
    print(f"Client connection from {path}")
    json_data = {"message": "Hello from the WebSocket server!"}
    await websocket.send(json.dumps(json_data))

async def start_server(port):
    async with serve(echo, "localhost", port):
        print(f"WebSocket server running on port {port}")
        await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()

async def main():
    ports = [20000, 20001, 20002, 20003, 20004, 20005]

    tasks = [start_server(port) for port in ports]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())


Thank you, how can this be modified to use a different handler for each Port or identify the port being accessed within the handler so it can handle each port differently?
